# Generate a random number from 0 to 100

Tags: swift

This is my current code:

```
let min = UInt32(0)
let max = UInt32(100)

@IBOutlet weak var percent: UILabel!

@IBAction func finalButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    func randNum (min: Int , max: Int) -> Int {
        return min + Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(max - min + 1)))

    }
    percent.text = "\(randNum)+'%'"
}
```

When I run this it works fine, up until the button is pressed, then I get a signal error, although all my code is connected when I look in the connection inspector. Is there an error in this code?

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting?

Comment: The string is wrong. But the real question is whether percent is nil.

Comment: I am getting the 'thread 1: signal sigabrt' error, highlighting '@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {'

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for something more like this:

```
let min = 0
let max = 100

@IBOutlet weak var percent: UILabel!

func randNum (min: Int , max: Int) -> Int {
    return min + Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(max - min + 1)))
}

@IBAction func finalButton(sender: UIButton) {
    let randomNumber = randNum(min, max: max)
    percent.text = "\(randomNumber)" + "%"
}
```

The `randNum` function you're using is looking for `Int` types to be passed into it. You're not passing any values to the function. Also, you have your `randNum` function inside your `UIButton` function. Is there a specific reason for this?

Comment: this worked thank you so much!! one last thing is there a way to tweak this code so that the button can only be pressed once?

Comment: @user3277295 Create an `outlet` to your `UIButton` and add `finalButton.enabled = false` to your `UIButton` action.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
let randomNumber = randNum(min, max)
percent.text = "\(randomNumber)%"
```

Comment: Sorry, randNum(0, 100)

Comment: still gives me the same error. Do I have to add anything next to 'UIViewController' could that be the problem?

Comment: also check if your percent label connected correctly

Comment: Also your min and max constants are not used. Perhaps you expected them to be used by your local function randNum but in fact you have defined two new parameters called min and max which you have to pass in when you call randNum - as ChikabuZ showed in his answer.